# How to get current YouTube IDs via iMacros?

Tags: javascript, youtube, imacros

I want to get the currently viewed YouTube video ID and save to CSV via iMacros, but it gets nothing. Here is the JS code:

```
var videoid;
videoid ="CODE:";
videoid +="URL GOTO=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBNYwxDZ_pA"+"\n";
videoid +="ADD !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}"+"\n";
videoid +="SET !VAR1 EVAL(\"var s=\"{{!URLCURRENT}}\"; s.match((?<=watch\\?v=|/videos/|embed\\/)[^#\\&\\?]*);s[0]; \")"+"\n";
videoid +="ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR1}}"+"\n";
videoid +="SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=url.csv"+"\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var videoid = "URL GOTO=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBNYwxDZ_pA" + "\n";
videoid += "SET !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}" + "\n";
videoid += 'SET !EXTRACT EVAL("\'{{!EXTRACT}}\'.match(/v=(.{11})/)[1];")' + "\n";
videoid += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=url.csv" + "\n"; 
iimPlayCode(videoid);
```

Comment: Could you help again? If the url change to :`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7aILQZgN-8&edit=vd`
`https://www.youtube.com/watch?edit=vd&v=X2e05EcG1kU`
how to use the match to get the ID?Thanks?